# Try that T-shirt on or Try on that T-shirt

Tags: usage, phrases

> 1. Can I try that T-shirt on?
> 2. Can I try on that T-shirt?

I look at the [dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/try-sth-on) it says 'try sth on' could be used like

> Try on the shoes, or
>    try it on for size

So it seem both sentences 1 and 2 are correct. But I think the sentence 2 is more likely to be correct.

please help me clear the confusion.

Comment: According to this reference about [***try on***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/try+on), *try on* as a phrasal verb is the best choice. But read the "Usage Note" too.

Comment: A related __[question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472/is-there-any-rule-about-splitting-phrasal-verbs)__, you might read an answer there. This is called "splitting a phrasal verb", and it's okay, unless you put too big an object between the verb and the preposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the four sentences are grammatically correct.

we are often confused about the place of object nouns/pronouns in a phrasal verb.
To make it clear, we can use the object noun either before or after the preposition, but we use the object pronoun only before the preposition.

Can I try on that shirt? and Can I try that shirt on? are grammatically correct, without any difference in sense, but we can't say "Can I try on it". The correct English is "Can I try it on?". Similarly, we can say "try on the shoes" or "try the shoes on", but we can't say "try on it".